# Problem trying tesseract with other languages

Tags: tesseract

I've just installed tesseract to try to write a python script. It works fine except when I try to use other languages.
In windows 10 terminal I tried to see what kind of results it obtains with english and it works fine except for a few german letters.
So I installed a few other languages to do some tests:

```
tesseract --list-langs
List of available languages in "C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/" (12):
chi_sim
chi_tra_vert
deu
ell
eng
equ
grc
ita
jpn
lat
osd
spa
```

But when I give the command...

```
tesseract german.jpg stdout -l deu
```

result:

```
Error opening data file C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/deu.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'deu'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.
```

I set the tessdata_prefix manually but it's like it doesn't recognize it.

```
TESTDATA_PREFIX
C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, it was a problem with the language files. I replace them with the correct ones and now it works.
Thanks.